# ORACLE CONVERT DATE TO VARCHAR2 return wrong date

Tags: oracle, date, to-char, sysdate

I am having a problem with date conversion to varchar2 type like in following example:

```
TABLE TEST

Name  Type          Nullable Default Comments 
----- ------------- -------- ------- -------- 
DESCR VARCHAR2(100) Y                         
DATA  DATE          Y                         
DATA2 VARCHAR2(500) Y  


execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM''';
DELETE FROM TEST;
INSERT INTO TEST SELECT 'SOME TEXT', SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;   


1 SOME TEXT "19/03/2015 12:05:45" "28/12/1393 12:05:45 TARDE"
```

When inserting in the table the SYSDATE converting to_char to a varchar2 field the date is `28/12/1393`.

Comment: why do you use `execute immediate` if the alter session is not dynamic ?

Comment: Just to make sure the date format is the same i'm using to convert. 
The date returns wrong even without the execute command or if i just use to_char(sysdate).
This block runs in one JOB

Comment: I mean you dont need the `execute immediate` part, you can directly call `alter session`.

Comment: What happens if you execute your SELECT directly? `SELECT SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM dual;`

Comment: @PeterLang 
The return is correct. The error only happens when insert into a varchar2 variable or a varchar2 collumn

Answer (score 0):

The following works ok for me (on 11.2.0.2, using client 11.2.0.2):

```
column descr format a12
column data2 format a30

create table test (descr varchar2(100),
                   data date,
                   data2 varchar2(500));

begin
  execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM''';
end;
/

DELETE FROM TEST;

INSERT INTO TEST SELECT 'SOME TEXT', SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;   

commit;

select * from test;

drop table test;
```

The select returns:

```
DESCR        DATA                   DATA2                         
------------ ---------------------- ------------------------------
SOME TEXT    19/03/2015 12:17:00 PM 19/03/2015 12:17:00 PM
```

Can you run the same test case and confirm that the select does indeed return incorrectly?

Also, what is your Oracle db version, and what is your Oracle client version?

ETA: sudden thought... there's not a trigger on your table that updates the date in the varchar2 column, is there?

Comment: There is no trigger in this table.

If i dont run as a job, it returns the correct date.

Comment: Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0 - 64bit Production

PL/SQL Release 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

CORE 11.2.0.1.0 Production

TNS for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

NLSRTL Version 11.2.0.1.0 - Production

Answer (score 0):

I run it as a job, so I changed a bit your script:

```
create table test (descr varchar2(100),
               data date,
               data2 varchar2(500));

create procedure testt is
begin
execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM''';


DELETE FROM TEST;

 INSERT INTO TEST SELECT 'SOME TEXT', SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;  

commit;

end;
/
declare
job number;
begin
DBMS_JOB.Submit(
                job => JOB,
                what => 'testt();',
                next_date => SYSDATE
                );
                commit;
end;
/

SELECT * FROM TEST;

DROP TABLE TEST;
DROP PROCEDURE TESTT;
```

And I got the result:

```
Connected to Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.2.0.1.0

Connected as 

SQL>

SQL> create table test (descr varchar2(100),

 data date,

 data2 varchar2(500));

Table created

SQL> create procedure testt is

 begin

 execute immediate 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = ''DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM''';

 DELETE FROM TEST;

 INSERT INTO TEST SELECT 'SOME TEXT', SYSDATE, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'DD/MM/YYYY HH:MI:SS AM') FROM DUAL;

 commit;

 end;

16 /

Procedure created

SQL> declare

 job number;

 begin

 DBMS_JOB.Submit(

 job => JOB,

 what => 'testt();',

 next_date => SYSDATE

 );

 commit;

end;

/

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

   SQL> SELECT * FROM TEST;

    DESCR DATA DATA2

    -------------------------------------------------------------------------------- ----------- --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    SOME TEXT 19/03/2015 28/12/1393 01:47:57 TARDE
```

Comment: And what if you don't run it as a job?

Comment: Hmm, I just ran your script, and it inserted the correct value into the data2 column. Very bizarre. I can't see how you could be getting the incorrect value. Maybe time to raise an SR with support?

Comment: Maybe. This error happens in only 1 db i've checked, noone of the others have this bug and they are all at the same version.